# How to select a text box on a webpage

Tags: c#, webforms, textbox, html

How can I select a text box that is available on a webpage so that my program can add data to the selected text box?

I am trying to setup a C# program that will auto login to a series of websites.

Example website:

http://what.cd/login.php

Current Code:

```
private void login()
{
        System.Net.HttpWebRequest whatCDReq = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.WebRequest.Create("http://what.cd/login.php");

        HTMLDocument htmlDoc = new HTMLDocumentClass();

        htmlDoc = (HTMLDocument)webBrowser1.Document;

        HTMLInputElement username = (HTMLInputElement)htmlDoc.all.item("p", 0);

        username.value = "Test";
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by "selecting a texbox on a webpage"? what kind of program is your program?

Comment: automatic login for a series of websites in C# - C# was in the title but was edited out, not sure why...

Comment: I assume  that you're trying to fill input fields on a distant webserver programmatically. Have a look at the [HttpWebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.aspx), the [NameValueCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.specialized.namevaluecollection.aspx) class and this SO-answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7023046/sending-namevaluecollection-to-http-request-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look, what you want to do is send form requests to the server. Parse the webpage for text box form controls and submit the data in a format that the server can use (usually, the data handling is done within PHP on the server end).

Look in the webpage file for a reference to the Javascript function that performs the action itself (it should format the data and send it to the server). I'd recommend implementing that by translating it to your language of choice OR you could run the Javascript function directly through some 3rd party library (despite what you may think, I find that the first option is ultimately easier for small tasks like this).

Comment: I think I understand, I will be trying to do it in C#. I am trying to setup a automatic login program for a series of websites. For example http://what.cd/login.php which as you said is PHP :P

Comment: Just to add to this: having looked at the page, it "POSTS" the data entered into form to [what.cd/login.php](what.cd/login.php), so you wouldn't need to even touch or scrape the page if you didn't want to. You could do something like this [blog shows](http://www.dijksterhuis.org/simple-class-to-submit-post-a-web-form-from-csharp/). The only downside to this is that if the login page changes, you'd have to change your code too.

Comment: Thanks :) I can't seem to get HttpUtility.UrlEncode(value))); to work as HttpUtility is not recognised, I am already using system.web http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx